# Why do I get so many warnings building Haskell with optl-static in Docker?

Tags: docker, haskell, static-linking, haskell-stack

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-15.4 as haskell
ENV STACK_ROOT /home/stackage/.stack
WORKDIR /opt/build
COPY Main.hs .
RUN stack ghc --package process -- -optl-static Main.hs

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=haskell /opt/build/Main /Main
ENTRYPOINT ["/Main"]
```

Here's my Main.hs

```
import System.Process (readProcess)
import Control.Monad (forever)
main = forever $ do
    output <- readProcess "/bin/ls" [] ""
    print output
```

Warning output has these two lines. I can probably just switch versions of Stack LTS to one that's supported fully. I'm not sure which versions those are but probably an easy fix.

> Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using
>   8.8.2, this may fail Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail

The rest have to do with static linking which I'd like to do to reduce my build size and avoid needing a bigger base package or adding dynamic packages when building into my binary seems easier.

Two lines like this:

> /home/stackage/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.2/lib/ghc-8.8.2/process-1.6.7.0/libHSprocess-1.6.7.0.a(runProcess.o):runProcess.c:function
>   runInteractiveProcess: warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically
>   linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the
>   glibc version used for linking

Ten or so lines like this:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(pthread_mutex_init.o)(.note.stapsdt+0x14):
>   warning: relocation refers to discarded section

About 30 lines like this:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.a(slowexp-avx.o)(.note.stapsdt+0x60):
>   warning: relocation refers to discarded section

How can I clear up these warnings?

Comment: For now, the first warning can only be reverted by using an older LTS, at least until Stack testing catches up.